# SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI not set

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I tried to work with `CURD` operation using `Flask` and `SQLAlchemy`.But getting `Error` while connecting to database.

Here is the `Error` log.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:819: UserWarning: SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI not set. Defaulting to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI not set. Defaulting to '
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:839: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
```

here is my **code & setup**

```
# database.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
sqldb = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/myDbName"


# create app
def create_app():
    sqlDB = SQLAlchemy(app)
    sqlDB.init_app(app)
    sqlDB.create_all()
    return app
```

here is models.py

```
from ..database import create_app
sqldb = create_app()
#  Users Model
class Users(sqldb.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = sqldb.Column(sqldb.Integer, primary_key = True)
    db = sqldb.Column(sqldb.String(40))
    def __init__(self,email,db):
        self.email = email
        self.db = db
    def __repr__(self,db):
        return '<USER %r>' % self.db
```

here is routes.py

```
# Import __init__ file
from __init__ import app
import sys
# JSON 
from bson import dumps
# login
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def login():
    try:
        # import users model
        from Model.models import Users,sqldb
        sqldb.init_app(app)
        sqldb.create_all()
        getUser = Users.query.all()
        print(getUser)
        return 'dsf'
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return "error."
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You probably need to put this line `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql..."` before the `SQLAlchemy(app)` instanciation.

Another option is to create `SQLAlchemy()` without parametters, to configure URI, and finally to tell `SQLAlchemy` to link with your app via `sqldb.init_app(app)`

Note that it is what you've done in your `create_app` function, but you never use it ?

Comment: Thanks @B. Barbieri  :) now error is gone but there is come new error.  The sqlalchemy extension was not registered to the current application.  Please make sure to call init_app() first.

Comment: It's not really clear where this comes from, mainly because your imports are quite a mess ... You probably need to remove this `create_app` function, and to make all your imports from `database.py` : this will prevent you from trying to use `sqldb` before it's fully configured.

Answer (score 4):

Like the answer above, if you use it this way, change

```
sqldb = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

to

```
sqldb = SQLAlchemy()
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error, and it was gone after setting the FLASK_APP environment variable :

```
export FLASK_APP=run.py
```

Start the application :

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occurs when `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']` is not set. You can set it as `True` or `False` like so:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

or

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
```

Answer (score -1):

Your method create_app returning a Flask() object called app

In the models.py module your variable sqldb should be pointing to sqlDB from code&setup file