# Creating a database using flask, Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a problem creating a database using flask, Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set; I always get this error

> Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting
> SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///friends.db'

class Friends(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
            return '<Name %r>' % self.id
```

Comment: Your question might not be well-received for such a non-descriptive and verbose non-title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask-SQLAlchemy: Neither SQLALCHEMY\_DATABASE\_URI nor SQLALCHEMY\_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY\_DATABASE\_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57720565/flask-sqlalchemy-neither-sqlalchemy-database-uri-nor-sqlalchemy-binds-is-set-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the db URI config to the line before instantiating a sqlalchemy object. Otherwise SQLAlchemy won't receive that data during instantiation.

#### Solution

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///friends.db' # Don't have this line below the next
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```